# SOURCEMGMT: Failed to resolve source MainEngineThread is returning 1612

Tags: wix

There is a user in Turkey that gets the following error simply by double clicking on the .msi to install a program: "The installation source for this product is not available.  Verify that the source exists and that you can access it."

He is the only user that I know of that is having this problem (of hundreds of users).  I believe he may have corrupted something about his environment.  I don't know all of the details, but I know he is using Windows 7 and has recently tried to manually migrate a lot of data from one user to another user (user D&C was migrated to user DC); this is not the only thing he has had errors with.

I had him turn on verbose logging and this is what I get.  I am still pretty new to using WiX and I would greatly appreciate any direction on how to even diagnose what the problem is or approaches to try and resolve his problem. Or at least, what does it mean that it "Failed to resolve source"?

```
=== Verbose logging started: 11/19/2014  1:42:26  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.7601.00        
Calling process: C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe === 
MSI (c) (5C:40) [01:42:26:658]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg 

MSI (c) (5C:40) [01:42:26:658]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg 

MSI (c) (5C:F4) [01:42:26:668]: Resetting cached policy values 
MSI (c) (5C:F4) [01:42:26:668]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0 
MSI (c) (5C:F4) [01:42:26:668]: ******* RunEngine: 
       ******* Product: C:\Users\DC\Downloads\LDSTradosStudioPlugin_6.4.msi 
       ******* Action: 
       ******* CommandLine: ********** 
MSI (c) (5C:F4) [01:42:26:668]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0 
MSI (c) (5C:F4) [01:42:26:670]: User policy value 'SearchOrder' is 'nmu' 
MSI (c) (5C:F4) [01:42:26:670]: User policy value 'DisableMedia' is 0 
MSI (c) (5C:F4) [01:42:26:670]: Machine policy value 'AllowLockdownMedia' is 1 
MSI (c) (5C:F4) [01:42:26:670]: SOURCEMGMT: Looking for sourcelist for product {2CF25F13-12F8-4B54-AC62-0F29F54E4F54} 
MSI (c) (5C:F4) [01:42:26:670]: SOURCEMGMT: Adding {2CF25F13-12F8-4B54-AC62-0F29F54E4F54}; to potential sourcelist list (pcode;disk;relpath). 
MSI (c) (5C:F4) [01:42:26:670]: SOURCEMGMT: Now checking product {2CF25F13-12F8-4B54-AC62-0F29F54E4F54} 
MSI (c) (5C:F4) [01:42:26:670]: Note: 1: 2718 2: {2CF25F13-12F8-4B54-AC62-0F29F54E4F54} 
MSI (c) (5C:F4) [01:42:26:670]: SOURCEMGMT: Failed to resolve source 
MSI (c) (5C:F4) [01:42:26:670]: MainEngineThread is returning 1612 
=== Verbose logging stopped: 11/19/2014  1:42:26 ===
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few times I have encountered "strange" errors with msi that relate to access problems.  I am not sure if this is one or not.

Is this user someone with higher security on their machine?  Did they download your MSI from the web (or network share)?  There were some customers of ours that ran into a problem where after they downloaded the item, they had to "unlock" the file before being able to run it.  Check to see if the end-user has to unlock this (as I recall it was through right-click on the properties of the file).

Secondly, are they trying to run this from a network share?  Make sure they copy the file locally first, sometimes that will cause access errors when running MSI's in secure environments.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback.

Is this user someone with higher security on their machine? [dfritch] I don't believe so.  He just said he is using his home computer.  Did they download your MSI from the web? [dfritch] Yes.  

Do you have any other information about "unlocking" a file?  I will look into that.

He is not trying to run it from a network share.  He did download the MSI from the web, and I e-mailed him one directly.

Comment: Re: Unlocking... I tried to find the old emails I had that described the issue, but unfortunately I cannot.  The customer's environment automatically encrypted the file when downloading (to prevent items from running automatically and for security purposes). They had to right-click the file, and go to the "Properties" window. From there they could "Unlock" the file with a button on one of the tab pages (sorry, I cannot remember more -- this was a couple years ago).